# Installing gsutil on Windows

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm relatively new to python so apologies if this is a dumb question.

I'm having trouble installing gsutil on Windows

I'm following the directions here

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#specifications

I've had to install python 2.7 and unzip gsutil in C:\gsutil\gsutil

the directions say to run the following code in the python command prompt

```
python gsutil
```

I'm getting this error

```
  File "<interactive input>", line 1
  python gsutil
              ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is find where "python.exe" and "gsutil.py" sit on your local system, like

```
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\gsutil\gsutil\gsutil.py
```

So hit Win+R, cmd, Enter to get into a command prompt, and do a

```
cd C:\Python27
```

Then you want to call the python interpreter on the gsutil.py file, like

```
python.exe C:\gsutil\gsutil\gsutil.py <COMMAND HERE>
```

And it should work.  For your initial configuration, you would run:

```
python.exe C:\gsutil\gsutil\gsutil.py config -b
```

And a web-browser would pop open for completing the setup.  There are some other nuances, but mostly "python.exe C:\gsutil\gsutil\gsutil.py COMMAND" is an exact replacement for "gsutil COMMAND" including all flags, so a long command like:

```
type my_list_to_upload.txt | python.exe C:\gsutil\gsutil\gsutil.py -m cp -I gs://.../ > output.txt
```

Will work.

Comment: awesome thanks for this. i didn't know how to use python when i posted it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running the command from the python shell. You want to run it from the Windows command-line prompt.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Python 2.7 and extracting gsutil.zip to your C drive, create a little batch script with these two lines:

```
@echo off
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\gsutil\gsutil.py %*
```

Put it in a folder like C:\Users\You\bin and add that folder to your PATH variable.

Now you can use `gsutil` from anywhere in your Windows CMD

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have the same problem as mine. But for what I did, I open command prompt, and install the gsutil by using pip command (make sure pip and python installed).

> pip install gsutil

Then, try run the gsutil after installation.